# Showing error messages using SweetAlert library

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Am working on an application whereby am validating on the backecnd (using PHP) and displaying the errors on the frontend,, am passing the errors using AJAX. All is working well except that I need to display the errors in **ordered list format** using **sweet alert js library**.

The errors are displaying but the problem is they aint being aligned in an ordered list manner:

**Sweet alert Js link**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

**Ajax code**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getplans",
            data:JSON.stringify(type),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                //Redirect
                window.location.href="getp" ;
            },
            //Alert errors from backend
            error: function(data) {
                //Unblock the spinner
                $.unblockUI();
                var errors = '';
                for(datos in data.responseJSON){
                    errors += data.responseJSON[datos] + '\n';
                }
                //Sweet alert js function
                swal(errors, "warning");
            }
        });
```

Comment: The code you posted is mostly unrelated to the problem. You need to show an example API response and your attempt at trying to wrap it in `<ol><li>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just take the nodes inside the `ul` element like this:

```
swal("Error:", document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].innerText)
```

and write them as text.
Below a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //swal("Error:", document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].innerText)

    let array = ['cofee', 'Tea', 'mill'];
    let list = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        list += array[i] + '\n';

    swal("Error", list);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `content` option. take took at [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-dom-nodes-as-content) example

Comment: I dont need an input field,, I only need how to show the errors in an ordered list format in sweet alert Js

Comment: it is possible to add any DOM element you need.
also you can use [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) which has many extra features.